# Adding selected to option drop down list based on user's previous selection

Tags: php

In the vendor drop down menu I need to dynamically add "selected" based on what the user input at the previous screen. I have what I think the loop will basically look like but I can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated, I have looked at other examples but they are not like this one. Here is my code:

```
 <?php  
 $set_date =$_POST['set_date'];
 include "../include/setup.inc.php";
 $query="select * from quote_distro where set_date ='2011-10-05'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$result) {echo "<p><b>".$query ."</b></p>";echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error(); return;}
echo '<br /><br />';
echo '<form name="edit_quote_setting_'.$row['qdid'].'" action="'.$self.'" method="post"><table align="center" border="1" width="800px">
               <tr><td width="10%">Email:</td><td width="20%"><input type="text" MAXLENGTH=40 size="30" name="email" value="'.$row['agent_email'].'"></td>
                <td width="10%">#Quote:</td><td width="10%"><input type="text" MAXLENGTH=4 size="3" name="num_quote" value="'.$row['num_quote'].'"></td>
                </td><td width="10%">Vendor</td><td width="40%"><select id="vendor1" name="vendor[1]">      
                        <option value="Regent Seven Seas Cruises"'.test().'>Regent</option>
                        <option value="Silversea Cruises">Silversea</option> 
                        <option value="Oceania Cruises">Oceania</option> 
                        <option value="Windstar Cruises">Windstar</option>
                        <option value="Paul Gauguin Cruises">Paul Gaugin</option>
                        <option value="all"> - No Preference - </option>
                        </select></td>
                <td><input name="qdid" type="hidden" value="'.$row['qdid'].'" />
                <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit"  class="go" value="Update Quote Setting" />
                </tr></form><table>';           
        }
        function test(){
        $vensel = $row['vendor'];
        if($vensel = "Regent Seven Seas Cruises" ){ echo "selected" }
        }//etc for each option
                ?>
```

Comment: `$array = array('Regent Seven Seas Cruises','Silversea Cruises','Oceania Cruises','Windstar Cruises','Paul Gauguin Cruises','all');                                               foreach ($array as $cruise){
         if ($cuise ==     $row['vendor']) {
         $test = '';
          echo $test;
         }
         else{
         $test = 'selected';
          echo $test; 
         }
         }` @someone, @nkorth here is what I have come up with, my boss wants me to use the variable but I think this is the wrong method. It loops and works but not for individual <option></option> HELP

Answer (score 2):

Your code could use some redesign, but here's a suggestion to start: Make an array of your cruise lines, and iterate over that array to output the  tags, and have your logic to determine which is selected in there.

```
$array = array('Regent Seven Seas Cruises', 'Silversea Cruises', 'etc');
foreach ($array as $cruise) {
    echo "<option value=\"$cruise\"";
    if ($row[vendor] == $cruise) echo ' selected="selected"';
    echo ">$cruise</option>";
}
```

Comment: What if the value and <option>x</option> are different?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Try calling `test` like this:

```
'<option value="Regent Seven Seas Cruises"'.test($row['vendor'],"Name of Cruise").'>Regent</option>'
```

and then implementing `test` like this:

```
function test($vensel,$cruisename){
    if($vensel == $cruisename){ 
        return "selected"; 
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

There are other ways to do this, but this way is the one requiring the fewest changes to your current code. The problem with your code is that variables have [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), and cannot be accessed outside of where they were created unless you pass them as parameters.

**EDIT:**

Here's another way to do it. Just put the below directly in the code, not inside a method. If you need to put it in a method, pass `$row['vendor']` as a parameter.

```
$values = array('Regent Seven Seas Cruises','Silversea Cruises','Oceania Cruises','Windstar Cruises','Paul Gauguin Cruises','all'); 
$texts = array('Regent Seven Seas','Silversea','Oceania','Windstar','Paul Gauguin ',' - No Preference - ');
$len=min(count($values),count($texts));
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
{
  echo '<option value="' . $values[$i] . '"';
  if($cruise == $row['vendor'])
  {
      echo ' selected';
  } 
  echo '>';
  echo $texts[$i];
  echo '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you someone! That's what was causing my confusion!

Comment: @hacktheplanet1337 You should _definitely_ consider using arrays here. If you want, I can post code for that method in an answer.